# Authentication with google firebase and spring

Tags: spring, firebase, spring-boot, spring-security, firebase-authentication

I want to use auth from google firebase, and integrate it with spring boot.
I am not sure that I have good idea how to implement roles/authorities.
I have in mind this scenario:

1. On success authentication with firebase, frontend send request to secured spring backend endpoint, and data on this endpoint contains which roles should user have, so frontend use this data to set claims for user. Backend use claims to authorize user when accessing endpoints.

Is this okey, or is there faster/better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a good approach. Have a look at the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) as that'll be your starting point once your backend receives the token from the client.

The only addition I can make at this point is that many of Firebase's own backend services cache recently decoded tokens (with the undecoded token as the key) to allow subsequent requests to more quickly look up the information for that token. While this is not required, it's an easy speed up once you're ready for that.

Comment: Okey, I did what I described above, everything works perfect but I have a question. What about refreshing token? I set custom claim to  my token ~1 hour ago, and user still have this claim. So I don't have to care if my claim will dissapear on token refresh or something like that? I have to set it only, when user gonna login after logout?

Comment: If a claim is added/removed, the ID token will change. Since we store the decoded values in the cache keyed by the ID token itself, this means we won't find any entry for the new ID token, we'll decode the new token and get the latest claims for the user.

Comment: So If I am understanding it correctly, on programming side, because of caching I have to set claims only once,  or when I will want just to change it, am I right?